# Node.js encrypts large file using AES

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I try to use following code to encrypt a file of 1 GB. But Node.js abort with "FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory". How can I deal with it?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var key = "14189dc35ae35e75ff31d7502e245cd9bc7803838fbfd5c773cdcd79b8a28bbd";
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
var file_cipher = "";
var f = fs.ReadStream("test.txt");
f.on('data', function(d) {
    file_cipher = file_cipher + cipher.update(d, 'utf8', 'hex');
});
f.on('end', function() {  
    file_cipher = file_cipher + cipher.final('hex');
});
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could write the encrypted file back to disk instead of buffering the entire thing in memory:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var key = '14189dc35ae35e75ff31d7502e245cd9bc7803838fbfd5c773cdcd79b8a28bbd';
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
var input = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt.enc');

input.pipe(cipher).pipe(output);

output.on('finish', function() {
  console.log('Encrypted file written to disk!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, how can I know when the encryption is done?

Comment: You can listen for the [`finish`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event on `output`.

Comment: How to decrypt the same file?

Comment: You can decrypt in the exact same way by using `crypto.createDecipher` instead of `crypto.createCipher`.

Comment: During decryption, how would I handle the wrong key? @RyanPlant

Comment: This work great but when i minimize my window streaming is stoped

Comment: [createCipher is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options)

Comment: For a similar program using up-to-date methods, see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370205/11609642).

Answer (score 12):

[crypto.createCipher()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) without initialization vector is deprecated since `NodeJS v10.0.0` use [crypto.createCipheriv()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) instead.

You can also pipe streams using [stream.pipeline()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) instead of `pipe` method and then promisify it (so the code will easily fit into promise-like and async/await flow).

```js
const {createReadStream, createWriteStream} = require('fs');
const {pipeline} = require('stream');
const {randomBytes, createCipheriv} = require('crypto');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const key = randomBytes(32); // ... replace with your key
const iv = randomBytes(16); // ... replace with your initialization vector

promisify(pipeline)(
        createReadStream('./text.txt'),
        createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv),
        createWriteStream('./text.txt.enc')
)
.then(() => {/* ... */})
.catch(err => {/* ... */});
```

With NodeJS 15+ you could simplify it (skip `promisify` part)

```js
const {createReadStream, createWriteStream} = require('fs');
const {pipeline} = require('stream/promises');
const {randomBytes, createCipheriv} = require('crypto');

const key = randomBytes(32); // ... replace with your key
const iv = randomBytes(16); // ... replace with your initialization vector

pipeline(
  createReadStream('./text.txt'),
  createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv),
  createWriteStream('./text.txt.enc')
)
.then(() => {/* ... */})
.catch(err => {/* ... */});
```

Comment: Me getting this error while decrypting the file `Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data`

Comment: @PrathameshMore It's difficult to say where the issue is without seeing the code for file decryption. Please note, you should store your key and initialization vector somewhere (e.g. file), `randomBytes` was used only for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Stream Promises API is available since Node Version 15 ([docu](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/stream.html#stream_streams_promises_api))

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use the [Fileger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fileger) to do it. It's a promise-based package and a clean alternative to the NodeJS filesystem.

```
const fileger = require("fileger")
const file = new fileger.File("./your-file-path.txt");

file.encrypt("your-password") // this will encrypt the file
   .then(() => {
      file.decrypt("your-password") // this will decrypt the file
   })
```