# Am I doing AES 256 encryption and decryption Node.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need to encrypt a chat message that will be stored a database. The data is a string of characters of various lengths. I want to use the native node.js crypto library and use a symmetric encryption protocol such as AES 256. I have concerns are the following:

1. Is CBC the correct AES mode for this use case for this type of field stored in a `TEXT` field in MySQL?
2. Does the key look like it is generated correctly?
3. Is the IV correct? Is prepending the IV to the encrypted text a proper way to do it or should it be a separate field?

```js
// AES RFC - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3602
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
// generate key with crypto.randomBytes(256/8).toString('hex')
const key = '6d858102402dbbeb0f9bb711e3d13a1229684792db4940db0d0e71c08ca602e1';
const IV_LENGTH = 16;

const encrypt = (text) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key, 'hex'), iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
  encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
  return `${iv.toString('hex')}:${encrypted.toString('hex')}`;
};

const decrypt = (text) => {
  const [iv, encryptedText] = text.split(':').map(part => Buffer.from(part, 'hex'));
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key, 'hex'), iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
  return decrypted.toString();
};

exports.encrypt = encrypt;
exports.decrypt = decrypt;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js encrypts large file using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345839/node-js-encrypts-large-file-using-aes)

Comment: @MattClark I believe this is not a duplicate because it provides an example that uses an IV and demonstrates decryption.

Comment: @MattClark does this seem better? This is really my concern. Also saying someone has a "terrible question" and shows "no effort"  doesn't seem to match the StackExchange Code of Conduct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: what are your concerns? This looks good to me on first look.

Comment: does this code work for you?

Comment: @Catalyst the code is working correctly.

Comment: @Lux I have improved my questions to more clearly state my concerns.

Comment: It seems that [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this question as it looks like you just want some opinions on working code and the answer does not provide any code, just a review on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is CBC the correct AES mode for this use case for this type of field stored in a TEXT field in MySQL?

Well, this depends a bit on your text. But probably yes.

> Does the key look like it is generated correctly?

yeah, looks good to me. It should look random and it looks random. Not sure what your concern is here.

> Is the IV correct? Is prepending the IV to the encrypted text a proper way to do it or should it be a separate field?

The IV looks good to me. I don't see many reasons why you shouldn't do it this way except one: its not very storage efficient. It would be far more efficient to store the data not as hex string but as binary data! And then you can't just use a colon to seperate the data. So either you know that its the first `n` bytes or you do a seperate field. Both has upsides and downsides, but both is ok. It's primary a question about style.

Comment: The text in this application are chat messages.

Comment: maybe consider using streams too

Comment: @Catalyst what benefit would that give me?

Comment: @jpotts18 it can allow you more stable memory usage & prevent you from blocking the event loop when a big payload needs to be processed, because it only blocks for a chunk at a time. With a chat app it probably will not buy you much.