# How to keep an encrypted file and read the file using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a set of passwords which I have saved in git repo. But I want to keep the file always encrypted. But in my automation, I should be able to decrypt and read data from that file.

Any idea how its possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js encrypts large file using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345839/node-js-encrypts-large-file-using-aes)

Comment: I use SOPS to do something similar, and use a KMS key from AWS. Your CD would then either make environment variables or config files from decryption

Comment: Warning: this is **not** secure unless you never, ever, even once, check the decryption key into git. Usually these sorts of secrets are handled with environment variables. Cybercreeps love to dig around on github looking for passwords to steal. If you have ever pushed that file to github unencrypted, change those passwords **now.**